# MongoDB - Understanding Indexes - db.explain

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am using mongoengine in python. For declaring my model I have the following code:

```
class Subject(Document):
    uri = StringField(required=True,unique=True)
    resources = ListField(ReferenceField('Resource'))
    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            {'fields': ['uri'], 'unique': True},
        ],
    }
```

I wanted to check that the index is created/ working as expected so I went to mongo and executed:

> db.subject.find({uri:'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Napoleon'}).explain()

The output of that command is the following:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor uri_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "uri" : [
            [
                "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Napoleon",
                "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Napoleon"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "ioannis-linux:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

What I can't understand looking at mongodb docs, is why we get two entries of the same uri index in `indexBounds`.What does this mean? This happens on any URI I look up.

**Update**

Not sure if this is relevant, but I have another domain class that is using the same URI as index as well..(`Resource`)

Comment: The lower index bound is inclusive, while the upper bound is exclusive. This basically reads "Find exactly this string in the index, no range".

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I have just an oldish 2.4 handy, so that might have changed, but it is not true in case of this explain. No matter the comparators (`$gte` v. `$gt`, `$lte` v. `$lt`), it always shows the same `indexBounds`. So it seems the ex/inclusivity (what's the correct word?) can not be determined from the explain.

Comment: @Fox: It is that way be definition. The index bounds only tells you what was used. And it works like expected: The index is used, the record is found and only one doc was read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is quite simple. Those are bounds - lower bound and upper bound. If those are equal, then you are searching for an exact string.

You could as well do something like

```
db.subject.find({uri: { $gte: 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Napoleon', 
                        $lte: 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Putin' 
                }).explain()
```

(though it does not make much sense in your case, it might be useful elsewhere), which would result in different bounds and thus a range result.

I'd say the reason behind this is simplification. Instead of having different fields to describe exact searches and range searches, this way you can express both.

Answer (score 1):

thats quite normal since you have a unique index on uri and you query for a single document on that index.
What indexBounds on explain tells you is that in order to retrieve this particular document it scanned the index starting at [lower, upper] bounds of this index which happen to be the same in this case since you specify a single document in query. nscanned = 1 verifies this too.

If you want to see different bounds try a query specifying a regex expression as: `{uri: {$regex:'^"http://dbpedia*'}}`  then probably it will have to scan more documents and you will get different [upper, lower] bounds in explain()